# How do I use two different images, one as a thumbnail and one as a linked image?

Tags: gallery

I wanted to do an image gallery in a post, where the linked image (a href) was different from the thumbnail's src.  Unfortunately, WP seems completely incapable of doing this.

If I put the large image in the gallery, I can't specify a custom thumbnail.  If I put the thumbnail in the gallery, I can't link the large image since "Link URL" appears to be broken.  If I change the "Link URL" and then click "Save All Changes," it ignores whatever changes I make in the "Link URL" text box.

Since there appears that there is no way to do this from the front end (which seems ridiculous?), I went looking through my web site's directories in an attempt to find where the blog posts are stored, but they're not on "/wp/" nor "/wp/wp-content", so I'm sort of stumped here!

Comment: simply put, you would like to have the image link to the post, instead of the images location. correct?

Comment: No.  I have a large image (1000x800), and I want a different image (cropped 150x150 version of it) to be used as the thumbnail.

Comment: Have you tried looking into WordPress' [post thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) or even [TimThumb](http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/). I would stick to WordPress' post thumbnails though, if your merely trying to crop images.

Comment: the custom thumbnail plugin used to be able to do that i think, but i'm not sure it is working any more.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, WP seems completely incapable of doing this......

A lit bit sensational? Just because you don't know how to do it doesn't mean WordPress cannot do it.

First many (if not most) themes do this by default, when you insert your image into a post ( in media gallery) you can choose thumbnails which will link to the larger image versions. By default there are 3 sizes, you can add more.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Images

You should look at these links for more advanced use for starters, but I have my doubts you will understand this:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size

WordPress uses MySQL, your blog posts are stored in a database not a directory...your images are stores in the /uploads folder based on date, you can change this setting in your admin.

Comment: I think the question was to use a completely custom thumbnail. Say you have a red square as the big image, and you want a green square as the thumbnail. It's also not about the_post_thumbnail(), but about the thumbnail defined in the media library, I think.